# Runtime equivalent of Maven filtering on Spring resources

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring application that contains a resource that I want to filter at runtime, using properties defined in an environment-specific configuration file.

For example:

```
class MyService {
    @Value("/WEB-INF/some-template.xml")
    private Resource resource;

    ...

    // Do something with the resource
}
```

In `/WEB-INF/some-template.xml`:

```
...
<system url="${myapp.url}"/>
...
```

In a properties file somewhere, perhaps read in via a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`:

```
myapp.url=http://test.myapp.com:1234
```

Note that the properties file is external from the application, as it is different in each environment.

I would like `MyService` to see the resource AFTER token replacement has taken place, i.e.

```
...
<system url="http://test.myapp.com:1234"/>
...
```

Is there any way of achieving this with Spring's property replacement mechanism? Or possibly a template engine that can interact with Spring `Resource` objects?